# WebGL THREE: changing position of obj, but the object doesn't move

Tags: three.js

I am working with an object which i loaded like this (I save it as a global variable such that I can change it later):

```
model1 = null; 

var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
  mtlLoader.load("http://blabla.mtl", function(materials) {
  materials.preload();
  var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
  objLoader.load("http://blabla.obj", function(object) {
    object.scale.x = 0.0004;
    object.scale.y = 0.0004;
    object.scale.z = 0.0004;
    object.rotateX(Math.PI / 2);  
    object.rotateZ(Math.PI / 2); 
    object.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(2))
    model1 = object;     //save in global variables
    scene.add(model1);
   });
});
```

When I am rendering I want to change the position of the model, based on a box's change in position:

```
function render(ms: number) {
  if (lastTime) {
    update((ms-lastTime)/1000) 
  }

  lastTime = ms
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  renderer.render( scene, camera )
}

var pos_current;
var pos_new;
var trans;

function update(dt: number) {
  if (pause.on) return


  //save position of box before it is transformed
  pos_current = box.position.clone();

  box.updatePosition()

  //save new position of box
  pos_new = box.position.clone();

  //transform the 3D-model according to the box's transformation
  trans = pos_current.sub(pos_new);

  model1.position.add(trans);
  console.log(model1.position)
```

I can in the console see that the position of model1 changes, but the object just doesn't move at all, and I can't really figure out why.

Any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: Do you set `object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;` anywhere? The `position`, `rotation`, and `scale` properties are just helpers, and are used when calculating the new matrices. Look at your `object.matrix` property to see if it's being updated when `position` updates.

Comment: No I don't do that - but now there actually seems to be a different problem, eventhough I haven't changed anything, which might have something to do with the above problem - now it seems that model1 is null, except for inside the obj-loader-function, so I can't access model1.position or model1.matrix at all

Comment: omg - I just got it to work - it's of course because it can't update the position of model1 when it isn't done loading it :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work - the problem was that I was trying to update the position of model1, before it was actually done loading in the obj-loader :D

Comment: I have a query. I too made a global variable and equaled it to object when loading. but it says in console log that variable in null. Is there a something I am missing

Answer (score 0):

I have a query. I too made a global variable and equaled it to object when loading. but it says in console log that variable in null. Is there a something I am missing.

Update:-
I understood the part where I am making the humanModel equal to object before it loaded but then how to handle it then?

```
let humanModel = null;

OBJLoader.load(
  // resource URL
  "/Models/Model_1(Malequins)/1/Cadnav.com_B0426014.obj",
  // called when resource is loaded
  function(object) {

    scene.add(object);

    humanModel = object; //adding the humanModel to the global variable

    camera.lookAt(object.position);
    console.log(object.position);
    console.log(camera.position);
  },
  // called when loading is in progresses
  function(xhr) {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
  },
  // called when loading has errors
  function(error) {
    console.log("An error happened " + error);
  }
);

console.log(humanModel.position);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can keep the object(obj file) in x,y or z direction, for it you need to set its position as:

```
var loader =  new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(
    '/models/female.obj',
    function(object){
        object.position.y=-20;
        scene.add(object);
    }
)
```